# '' Single quote syntax error in mysql but no single quotes in query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

The following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_staff_contract_contract_document_last_changed` BEFORE UPDATE ON `staff_contract`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (new.Contract_document != old.Contract_document) THEN
        SET new.Contract_document_last_changed = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
    END IF;
END;
```

fails with this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`.

However there's no single quotes in the query. If I remove the begin/end and if/else syntax it works, e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_staff_contract_contract_document_last_changed` BEFORE UPDATE ON `staff_contract`
FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.Contract_document_last_changed = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

It must be something to do with the begin/end or if/else, but I don't know what, any idea?

Comment: `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` is function why you are wrapping them in backticks ?

Comment: Remnant of some attempted debugging. I've removed them but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: The single quotes are not part of the query being quoted; they delimit it. In this case it's giving you an empty string, which is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

*By using the BEGIN ... END construct, you can define a trigger that executes multiple statements. Within the BEGIN block, you also can use other syntax that is permitted within stored routines such as conditionals and loops. However, just as for stored routines, if you use the mysql program to define a trigger that executes multiple statements, it is necessary to redefine the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger definition. The following example illustrates these points. It defines an UPDATE trigger that checks the new value to be used for updating each row, and modifies the value to be within the range from 0 to 100. This must be a BEFORE trigger because the value must be checked before it is used to update the row*

The problem is that you are using multiple statements and you should separate them with the statement delimiter which is the `;` character by default.

**EDIT** Some extra details:

The default delimiter and the delimiter used in the trigger's body is the same and  MySQL thinks that the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement ends at the first `;` character. In this case this means that there is a syntax error (since the `BEGIN..END` block and the trigger is not finished).

The '' in the error message means, that there is an empty statement, not a single or double quotation mark.

You have to change the delimiter to successfully create the trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `Update_staff_contract_contract_document_last_changed` BEFORE UPDATE ON `staff_contract`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (new.Contract_document != old.Contract_document) THEN
        SET new.Contract_document_last_changed = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. P.S. you spelled DELIMITER wrong at the end of your code example.